# Laravel Sanctum: Shifting user credentials - after some time the user logged in is now another user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, sanctum

When we do some user testing on our web app after some testing the user logged in shifts from the original to another one the other user does not have access to.

We checked the authentication part and our lead developer said this:

- "The issue is not on the authentication part as it follows Laravel standard as per documentation"
- "Session Handling - this no longer apply since the authentication is token-based"

Our tech stack is - Laravel Sanctum, Token-based authentication